# Factorize $6x^2 -5x -14 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quadratics

I'm throwing a bit of a blank on the best way to factor this :

$$6x^2 -5x -14 = 0$$

I know that I could multiply $6$ by $14$ and then find a pair of factors that add to $-5$ (b), but this feels a bit convoluted and I'm sure that I've gone about this a bit of an easier way before, I just can't remember how...

Does anyone know the simplest way?

cheers!

Comment: $(2x+\underline{  })(3x+\underline{  })$ or $(6x+\underline{  })(x+\underline{  })$. The blanks must multiply to $-14$ and so must be opposite signs.

Comment: @DavidPeterson - cheers, so in this case it'd be (6x + 2)(x-7) .... But that was still the method that I used before really wasn't it, ? Or is that just the simplest method? I may have imagined another one... just for larger numbers it can take a while sometimes.

Comment: Factoring in general is an **extremely hard** process. There are "shortcuts" for quadratics. Rarely do any of the tricks make it easier than informed trial and error or the quadratic formula

Comment: There is a formula that you should have or will have learned in the same unit called the "quadratic formula" which states that for $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the roots are $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  Personally I learned the formula using the melody for the song 'brother john'.  'negative b plus or minus squareroot bsquared minus four a c over two a'.  This will always give an answer even in messy numbers.

Comment: Vieta's formulas and common solution using discriminant (which are virtually the same for large values) is what have. By the way, your factorization is wrong, a correct one is $(x-2)(6x+7)$

Comment: Thanks all - guess it's just intuition based on experience with the trial and error then... or the formula. No worries, can I mark this as solved at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to factor by splitting and grouping.  To split the linear term of $6x^2 - 5x - 14$, we must find two numbers with product $6 \cdot -14 = -84$ and sum $-5$.  They are $-12$ and $7$.  Hence,

\begin{align*}
6x^2 - 5x - 14 & = 0\\
6x^2 - 12x + 7x - 14 & = 0 && \text{split the linear term}\\
6x(x - 2) + 7(x - 2) & = 0 && \text{factor by grouping}\\
(6x + 7)(x - 2) & = 0 && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}

If a product is equal to zero, then one of the factors must equal zero.  Hence,

\begin{align*}
6x + 7 & = 0 & x - 2 & = 0\\
6x & = -7 & x & = 2\\
x & = -\frac{7}{6}
\end{align*}

Note that if you want to check your factorization is correct, you form the product

\begin{align*}
(6x + 7)(x - 2) & = 6x(x - 2) + 7(x - 2)\\
                & = 6x^2 - 12x + 7x - 14\\
                & = 6x^2 - 5x - 14
\end{align*}
so factoring by splitting and grouping is simply performing the steps of multiplying two linear factors in reverse order. The reason it works is that if a quadratic polynomial splits into linear factors, then the product of the quadratic coefficient and constant term is equal to the product of the coefficients of the two linear terms into which it splits.  In this case, $6(-14) = (-12)(7)$. In general, if

$$ax^2 + bx + c = (mx + n)(px + q) = mpx^2 + (mq + np)x + nq$$

then $ac = (mp)(nq) = (mq)(np)$, where $mq + np = b$.

This is certainly more efficient than guessing the linear factors.  You could find the factors directly by completing the square (as Michael Hardy demonstrated), but this involves more work.  You could also find the factors by solving the equation using the Quadratic Formula, then working backwards to determine the factors (again, as Michael Hardy demonstrated).  However, if your goal is to solve the equation, you do not need to factor the quadratic if you have applied the Quadratic Formula to find the roots.

I will step off my soapbox now.

Comment: That's ace Taussig thanks for that explanation. I went through it on paper, when you use all the terms such as m, p, q etc... Are they convention? Do they represent anything? 

I can see that (mq+np) represents the `b` value of the original quadratic equation, but what I'm wondering is whether you chose these letters just because they're some letters or whether there's any convention / reason behind the choices. 

Was nice to read though thanks

Comment: I could have used any variables other than $a$, $b$, $c$, and $x$ for $m$, $n$, $p$, and $q$.  Here, $a = mp$, $b = mq + np$, and $c = nq$.  To see this, first set $x = 0$ in the algebraic identity $ax^2 + bx + c = (mx + n)(px + q)$.  This yields $c = nq$.  Setting $x = 1$ in the same identity yields $a + b + c = mp + mq + np + nq \Rightarrow a + b = mp + mq + np$.  Setting $x = -1$ in the same identity yields $a - b + c = mp - mq - np + c \Rightarrow a - b = mp - mq - np$.  Solving the resulting system of equations shows that $a = mp$ and $b = mq + np$.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got the quickest way. Another way is to multiply by $4\times 6 =24$ - where you would always have the $4$ and the $6$ would be the coefficient of $x^2$. This gives $$4\cdot6^2\cdot x^2-4\cdot 6 \cdot 5\cdot x-4\cdot 6\cdot 14=(12x-5)^2-25-336=(12x-5)^2-19^2=0$$ which keeps everything integral, and if there is a rational factorisation will come out nicely as the difference of two squares. If not, you get an irrational square root and it is wholly equivalent to the usual quadratic formula.

Here the difference of two squares factorises as $(12x-24)(12x+14)$ corresponding to $(x-2)(6x+7)$ for the original form.

---

In general starting with $ax^2+bx+c=0$ would go via $4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac=(2ax+b)^2-b^2+4ac=0$ and will come out nicely if $b^2-4ac$ is a square. The main feature of this method is that it completes the square without introducing fractions.

Comment: Thanks mark... When you say it keeps it integral, is that just referring to using integers rather than fractions?

Comment: @learner Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& 6x^2 - 5x - 14 \\[8pt]
= {} & 6\left( x^2 - \frac 5 6 x \right) - 14 \\[8pt]
= {} & 6\left( x^2 - \frac 5 6 x + \frac{25}{144} \right) - 14 - 6 \left(\frac{25}{144}\right) \quad\text{(completing the square)} \\[8pt]
= {} & 6 \left(\left( x - \frac 5 {12} \right)^2 - \frac{361}{144}\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & 6 \left(\left( x - \frac 5 {12} \right)^2 - \left(\frac{19}{12}\right)^2 \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & 6\left(x - \frac5{12} - \frac{19}{12}\right)\left(x - \frac5{12} + \frac{19}{12}\right) \quad\text{(factoring a difference of two squares)} \\[8pt]
= {} & 6(x-2)\left(x + \frac 7 6\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & (x-2)(6x+7).
\end{align}

If one says
$$
x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{5\pm\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot6\cdot(-14)}}{2\cdot6} = \frac{5\pm19}{12} = \left(\frac{24}{12}\text{ or }\frac{-14}{12}\right) = \left(2\text{ or }\frac{-7}6\right)
$$
then one knows that $x-2$ and $x-\left(\dfrac{-7}6\right)$ must be factors, and one must have $6$ as the leading coefficient, so one gets the same result.

The usual way to prove that
$$
x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
$$
if $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is by completing the square.