# Irreducible Polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to see if the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$: 
$P(X,Y)=X^2Y^3+XY^2+XY+8$

Is there any simple algorithme to prove it ?

Thanks

Comment: $P(X,1)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $X$

Comment: Thinks , but i'm really searching a general algorithm

Comment: There is no general algorithm.

Comment: @ASKASK What do you conclude from the fact that P(X,1) is an irreducible polynomial over X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[X][Y] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[Y][X]$$
So you can view $P(X,Y)$ as poynomial in $Y$ of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ or as polynomial in $X$ of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}[Y]$([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543991/factorize-the-polynomial-x3y3z3-3xyz/544042#544042)). A polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$, that is not irreducible, must have a linear factor. So assume that $(X-p(Y))$ is a linear factor of $X^2Y^3+X(Y^2+Y)+8$ from $\mathbb{Z}[Y][X]$.
$P(Y)$ must be a fraction $\frac{k}{s}$ where $k$ divisor of $8$ and $s$ is a divisor of $Y^3$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1776828/11206)). These are finitely many possibilities to check. None of them gives a solution.

Check the slightly different polynomial $P(X,Y)=X^2Y^3+XY^2+XY+1$ and you will find a factor with this method, because $(X+\frac{1}{Y})$ is a linear factor. This can be shown by checking that  $P(\frac{-1}{Y},Y)=0$ holds.